# Unable to move ASP.NET Identity model into another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, asp.net-identity

I have tried to follow the steps described in this link in order to pull out my identity class from the web application into its own class library.

http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2013/10/22/Moving_ASP_NET_Identity_model_into_another_assembly

I do as follows:

1. Created a web form project and named it `3TierExample`.
2. Created new class class library called `3TierExample.Model`.
3. Installed Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework package from NuGet into `3TierExample.Model`
4. Moved `identityModel.cs` to the new class library `(3TierExample.Model)`
5. Added a reference to `3TierExample.Model` in `3TierExample`

Then for the `identityModel.cs` I use the following references:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Web;
using System;
using _3TierExample.Models;
```

My namespace is as follows:

```
namespace _3TierExample.Models{…}
```

However when I finish I get the following errors:

> I:..\3TierExample\3TierExample\Default.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   I:...\3TierExample\3TierExample\Default.aspx 1   1   3TierExample
>
> Metadata file 'I:..\3TierExample\3TierExample.Model\bin\Debug\3TierExample.Model.dll' could not be found
>
> The type or namespace name 'HttpRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I:...\3TierExample
>
> The type or namespace name 'HttpResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    I:...\3TierExample

If I go to the web project I see that the reference to the newly created class library is there, so I don’t know how is it possible to get the first error (No 3). Then, the second error happens as a consequence, I think, of not finding the assembly reference. Why? The reference is there!?

Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @marc_s Hi Mark, Thank you for the comment. Yes I am aware of that, it was a typo I usually type very fast, and you will notice that it was right further up.  Anyway, I normally pass through a spell checker just in case but this time I have forgotten to do that. Good point though!  The more correct the clearer the question :0)

Comment: Spelling it correctly would allow you to type *even faster* (one less character to type, per *reference* :-) )!

Answer (score 0):

There is an assembly conflicts.

When you create project, it could be having old version *Asp.net Identity* assemblies. You installed latest Asp.net Identity Packages in your class lib proj. If you want to separate Asp.net Identity Context from the main project, you don't need that framework in your web proj.

you can set *No Authentication* while creating your web project, which make sure there will not be conflicts when reference to Asp.net Identity Class Lib Project. You may require to copy *IdentityModels.cs* from sample Web Project in order to use in Class Lib Proj.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am implementing your suggestion and it seems to work, what about the Account Folder and all its pages? Login, Manage, Register...These are automatically created when choosing project with individual account authentication, is there another option than setting it up from scratch?

Comment: i got it. *Account* folder you let it be there, ideally it should be using Asp.net Identity objects from your referenced class lib proj. You may need to import namespace or *Ctrl+.* will find UserManager/ApplicationUser or other objects itself.